# Douglas Peucker algorithm using counter

Tags: java, algorithm

Is it feasible to step through the douglas peucker line simplification algorithm using a counter to pause execution to show individual processing steps?
I am not sure if it is possible. If so would a particular data structure
be recommended to do this. I have only seen recursive solutions and am not sure if this is feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is certainly possible. If you are mostly interested in viewing the steps taken after the algorithm is complete then the easiest thing to do would be to just keep a copy of the list of points at each step in the algorithm. Once the algorithm is complete then you can print out the list of intermediate steps.

For example, if you are storing the points in a list then you could copy the list at each iteration:

```
class DouglasPeucker {
    private List<Point[]> steps = new ArrayList<>();

    public Point[] compute(Point[] points) {
        steps.add(points.clone());
        // perform normal recursive steps
    }

    public void printSteps() {
        for (Point[] points: steps) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is a shallow copy of the array - i.e. the point objects are not cloned. This will work fine if the point objects are immutable (which they probably should be).

Alternatively, if you want to stop at each point and examine the state of variables then you should use an interactive debugger with breakpoints at the appropriate places.

Comment: Thanks sprinter. Its good to know this is possible. At some point I had been trying to keep a copy of outputs I think I would need to make sure I am taking copies at the right places in my code. My implementation has two recursive calls before returned points are merged. I think my problem was I was trying to take a copy of the point data after the recursive calls i.e after resulting line data is merged back. Is the copy before the recursive calls the way to go